# Problem regarding equation of line in space

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, 3d, plane-geometry

I have doubt regarding similarity in equation of plane and equation of line in space.
I know that equation of form Ax +By+Cz+D=0 where A,B,C are nonzero represents a plane i.e we require 3 variables to get a specific eq of a plane.
Now suppose we have a cartesian eq of line
$\frac {x-1}{2} $ = $\frac {y-2}{3} $ =$ \frac{z}{4}$
we can reduce the above equation to 
x=2k+1, y=3k+2 , z=4k and eliminating k we get 
x+2y-2z=5 . Does this mean that equation of line has been converted to equation of plane. If not then what does the converted form of line represent ?

Comment: $x + 2y - 2z = 5$ is the equation of a plane that contains the line you initially described.  You "lost some information" when you "eliminated $k$".

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom suppose we have another eq of line x+1/2 =y+5/3 = z-6/ 4 converting it to eq of plane it is contained in i.e x+2y-2z=-23  can we find the distance bw these 2 line by finding distance bw these planes

Comment: @Physicsfreak there is no reason to believe that this should work

Comment: @Physicsfreak remember to put any mathematical expressions between dollar signs.  For instance, `$\frac{z}{4}$` becomes $\frac z4$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom okay one last question. A line may be contained in infinite no. of planes. Then why converting the equation like I did gives equation of a single plane

Comment: I don't know because I don't know how you "eliminated $k$"; you'll have to show the steps that you followed.

Comment: I simply did this x=2k+1, y=3k+2 , z=4k  added first 2 equations and subtracted the third one from them. Thanks for help with MathJax

Comment: What you call the Cartesian equation of a line is actually a system of two equations expressed in a compact form. Also, you did more than simply “eliminate $k$.” In the process, you also combined two equations into one, which is virtually guaranteed to lose information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started with the equations
$$
x = 2k+1, \quad y = 3k + 2, \quad z = 4k.
$$
By taking a linear combination of these equations, you found
$$
x + y - 2z = (2k + 1) + 2(3k + 2) - 2(4k) = 5.
$$
You can repeat this process with any $a,b,c$ to get the equation
$$
ax + by + cz = a(2k + 1) + b(3k + 2) + c(4k).
$$
We will have eliminated the constant on the right hand side if an only if we have
$$
2a + 3b + 4c = 0.
$$
In other words, we will get an equation of the form $ax + by + cz = d$ (for some constant $d$) if and only if the vector $(a,b,c)$ is perpendicular to $(2,3,4)$, which is the direction of the line.